# Wrapper Class for Win32 Shared Memory? (interprocess-communication)

Tags: c++, windows, ipc

what wrapper class can you recommend for IPC on Win32? I have tried [XQueue](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/XQueue.aspx), I found it slightly clunky, and would like to hear what else is out there. Building something on InterlockedPopEntrySList() seems nice but that requires server 2003.

Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend Qt4 (or you could check the source) : http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qsharedmemory.html

Comment: Thanks, QT seems like a fantastic framework. But without having had a deep look at this particular implementation, I have a feeling that I would have to include a fairly large chunk of that framework, in order to get this one feature. I could be wrong. Any comments?

Comment: It is LGPL, so I believe you can easily check the source code for it and include it in your code, unless your project's license isn't compatible with LGPL.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend [Boost Interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/interprocess.html), however you might prefer a more light weight version published [here](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184401648) (win32 only).

Answer (score 0):

Check out Boost's [interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/interprocess.html) library. It has all the building blocks you need to create a very clean IPC implementation via shared memory.